# How long should take to iterate over large txt file? / Python

Tags: python, performance, file, iterator

The code below is to be used to iterate over some large .txts.

10 minutes to iterate over a 80MB file: is that what I should expect? Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach?

```
print 'File size = ' + str(os.path.getsize(FullPath))
print time.gmtime()
with open(FullPath) as FileObj:
    for lines in FileObj:
        i +=1
print i
print time.gmtime()
```

OUTPUT:

```
File size = 80536606
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=15, tm_min=16, tm_sec=6, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=117, tm_isdst=0)
140614
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=15, tm_min=26, tm_sec=21, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=117, tm_isdst=0)
```

Based my code on these links:

[How to read large file, line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python)

[Looping through big files takes hours in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025919/looping-through-big-files-takes-hours-in-python)

Comment: is the program hogging your cpu?

Comment: @PhillipMartin. If I understand your question: Task manager shows CPU usage at 5%/6% and memory 3.something GB.

Comment: I ran your code on a csv that is 140MB and the time, including getting size of the file, to print the number of lines was just under 4 seconds.  So the approach seems right.  Move your big file to the folder you are running the code from, if you can, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Scott. Indeed I'm loading this file to memory from a server that I'm not even sure where's located. Now that I say that it's kind of obvious...

Comment: @BuckTurgidson I figured you were reading it from somewhere other than your machine.  That's probably the hang up.

Comment: Do you just want to get the number of lines in the file, or is that just some placeholder code?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI. Placeholder.